# Ode implementation of Maxwell Stefan's equation

Tags: ode

I am trying to solve Maxwell Stefan's equation over a membrane to get the transient mole fraction distribution over the membrane thickness 'z'. But somehow I am not able to code it using ODE45, more likely I am not able to write the system to solve using ODE45. It will be really great if someone can help me with the primary syntaxes and function. The equation I am trying to solve is

> `(dy_i)/dz=1/(cD_(i,j) ) [y_i (N_i+N_j )-N_i ]`

where c is concentration and D_(i,j) is binary diffusion coefficient.

Comment: Is there a sum on the right side, if not, what is `j` in relation to `i`? Is the division by the matrix elements individually or is this notation for the elements of the inverse of matrix `cD`?

Comment: Is this problem related to this: [Maxwell-Stefan diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Stefan_diffusion)?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Hello, You are absolutely right, it is a Maxwell Stefan equation for diffusion. i and j are not matrices but they are two species in a binary system.

Comment: To be within the guidelines of this network, you need to post the code of your previous best attempt. If you suspect that you do not have a problem with the matlab functions but with the mathematical model itself, you might be better served to move to scicomp.SE.

Comment: Actually I tried to write a code with this model using ODE45 but I don't know where to start, and all the codes available could not guide me towards a successful start! That is why I have not included a code with it.

Comment: Then your question is really off-topic, as SO deals with code-related questions, that is, questions about existing code and its bugs. Move the question to scicomp.SE, perhaps alternatively to physics.SE or math.SE and use mathjax to produce a more faithful reproduction of the differential equation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs! I will do so ASAP!